# How to upgrade Eclipse from Galileo to Helios on Ubuntu (10.04)

Tags: eclipse

From other related posts, the recommended "best practice" is to create a "parallel" installation of Eclipse 3.6 (Helios).  But I wish it were that simple ...

On my system, the installation package for 3.5 (Galileo) seems to have distributed the Eclipse system files over many different file-system locations:

```
/usr/lib/eclipse
/usr/bin/eclipse
/usr/share/
/var/lib/dpkg/info/
/etc/eclipse.ini
~/.eclipse
```

It's not at all clear to me what a "parallel" installation would look like in this case.  Can someone enlighten me?

Would I be better off just deleting everything other than my workspace files that appears to involve Eclipse, and try to do a clean install of Helios?

Thanks.

Comment: Software installation is better suited to superuser.

Answer (score 2):

I, personally, always download the ZIP package of Eclipse from `eclipse.org` and don't use the system's Eclipse package at all. It just makes everything cleaner. Then, when upgrading, I delete the old Eclipse folder, unzip the new one, and maybe keep options in `eclipse.ini`. The only difficulty is with the plugins but I keep links to the update sites so it's no big deal to download and install them again.